# Badge Number Control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, badge

Anyone know of a control that looks like the apple badge number icons? Looking to use it as an indicator but not in the default places Apple makes it available.

Does Apple have a control already I can use, or someone have something on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a loo here: [LKBadgeView](https://github.com/lakesoft/LKbadgeView). It is highly customizable.

[image: screenshot]